# Fastest way to convert Scala array to Java array

Tags: scala

I have a method in Java with this signature `void setActiveProfiles(String... profiles)`, and in Java I can pass an array of string to this method. I want to call the method and pass it an `Array[String]`, but I got `Type mismatch` error. And my question is what is the best and optimal way to convert Scala array to Java array?

This is the body of compilation error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Array[String]
 required: String
```

Comment: Can you display the error. Are you trying to send Java array to scala function?

Comment: No, I want to call the Java method with vararg parameter in Scala

Comment: I think my answer is `setActiveProfiles(array:_*)`

Comment: You dont have to do anything. If you have a java function and it expects a `String[]` then scala compiler will itself convert `Array[String]` to `String[]`. Please show the error

Comment: @Jatin No, because parameter type is Vararg

Comment: maybe you need to pass it as setActiveProfiles(profiles:_*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer and I've tested it, call method as `setActiveProfiles(array:_*)`

Comment: Perhaps you could change your question to match your answer?